# How can I develop using ODAC 12 for EF without interfere old Oracle versions?

Tags: entity-framework, odp.net, odac

I'm developing with VS 2013 (vb.net) and using ODAC12 with ODP.NET but the user have app that works with oracle 9 so when I install ODAC12 on his PC those app doesn't works.

I configured the app.config with connection string

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModeloRC.csdl|res://*/ModeloRC.ssdl|res://*/ModeloRC.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;data source=TNS;password=**;user id=**&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

anyway I cant use ODAC11 for develop, I tried but I cant make my entity data model *.edmx with vs 2013

how can I use ODAC12 without interfere others app with oracle 9

Answer (score 0):

There is the concept of an "Oracle Home" (directory) with the idea that software in each Oracle Home should not interfere with each other. So I would start by installing the client which your user needs and then also install the ODAC version that you need in a new Oracle Home (directory).

You should also remove the policy DLLs from the GAC if you do not want .NET apps built with an older version of ODP.NET to automatically use the new one.

For more complicated scenarios when using multiple versions of ODP.NET, please see the ODP.NET documention for configuration of the DLLPath parameter.

Also, investigate using the XCopy install which can allow you to embed ODP.NET with your application. And of course the ODP.NET, Managed Driver removes all of the "DLL Hell". :)